# Комментарии modx revo

Tags: cms, modx, revo

подскажите что не так, не выводит все комментарии на отдельной странице

вывожу вот так

```
[[!getPage?
                              &elementClass=`modSnippet`
                              &element=`getResources`
                              &class=`TicketComment`
                              &tpl=`tpl.Tickets.comment.latest.my`
                              &limit=`5`
                              &includeContent=`1`
                              &includeTVs=`1`
                              &processTVs=`1`
                              &tvPrefix=``
                              &parents=`2`
                              &depth=`10`
                              &pageLimit=`5`
                              &pageNavVar=`page.nav`
                            ]]

                        <div class="pagination-block">
                            <ul class="pagination" te>
                            [[!+page.nav:notempty=`
                            [[!+page.nav]]

                            `]]
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

сам чанк

```
<div class="col-md-4 item-r">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 title-r">
  <h3><a href="[[~[[+ticket.id]]]]#comment-[[+id]]">[[+ticket.pagetitle]] </a></h3>
  <h6>[[+ticket.content]]</h6>
</div>  
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 title-r">
  <p>[[+text:ellipsis=`250`]]</p>
</div>  
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 img-r">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="[[+avatar:phpthumbof=`w=300&h=300&zc=1`]]">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">[[+fullname]]</div>
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: getResources на pdoResources заменять пробовал?

Comment: да пробовал, все ровно не выводит ничего

Comment: &includeContent=`1`
                              &includeTVs=`1`
                              &processTVs=`1`
                              &tvPrefix=``
                              &parents=`2`
                              &depth=`10` - вот эти параметры лишние. их попробуйте убрать

Comment: ничего не выводит